# UnknownError: Graph execution error: Fail to find the dnn implementation. GOOGLE COLAB

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am trying to train a comment toxicity sequential model on colab but whenever i try to:

> Trained_Model = model.fit(train, epochs=6, validation_data=val)

i am running in following error =>

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-25-542b639be771> in <module>()
      1 #Training the model for 1-epoch for now (feel free to adjust it as per your system specs)
----> 2 Trained_Model = model.fit(train, epochs=6, validation_data=val)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

Fail to find the dnn implementation.
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[sequential/bidirectional/backward_lstm/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_16192]
```

Here is my code =>
https://colab.research.google.com/github/jay0x5/Speech-Toxicity/blob/main/SpeechToxicityDetector.ipynb?authuser=1#scrollTo=266428df

Please help me fix this

Answer (score 0):

for tensorflow version2,

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], enable=True)
```

Then start to create model and go further.
If such case it fails to work. Try to upgrading the CuDNN version by following this [link](https://jhui.github.io/2017/09/07/AWS-P2-CUDA-CuDNN-TensorFlow/). Hope this will work for you. For reference [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36508).

Comment: ahh sadly nope those lines throw me different error =>

```RuntimeError: Physical devices cannot be modified after being initialized```

Comment: Oh my bad..In your colab there is no need of any installation of tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu. Those things already in colab. That might cause the conflict. Remove the cell for installation of tensorflow-gpu and restart the runtime and try again to run. That will work.